# Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release packaging RedFX-Quantum/Strange

Tags: java, maven

attempting to build  [RedFX-Quantum/Strange][1]. When running mvn package, I get "Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release". the pom.xml file is below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.redfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>strange</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.1.3</version>
  <name>Strange</name>
  <description>Strange Quantum Simulator</description>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <javadoc.plugin.version>3.2.0</javadoc.plugin.version>
    <gpg.plugin.version>1.6</gpg.plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
<!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>nd4j-native</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.26</version>
    </dependency>
-->

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>10</release>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version> <!-- Use newer version of ASM -->
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>org.redfx.strange.demo.Demo</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.2</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <goals>
             <goal>test-jar</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
<!--
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.7</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
          <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
          <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
-->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-no-snapshots</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireReleaseDeps>
                  <message>Snapshot dependencies are not allowed for release project version!</message>
                  <onlyWhenRelease>true</onlyWhenRelease>
                </requireReleaseDeps>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
        <organizationName>Johan Vos</organizationName>
          <inceptionYear>2020</inceptionYear>
          <licenseName>bsd_3</licenseName>
          <addJavaLicenseAfterPackage>false</addJavaLicenseAfterPackage>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>ossrh</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
      <id>ossrh</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>release</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-sources</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${javadoc.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
              <detectJavaApiLink>false</detectJavaApiLink>
              <source>8</source>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
              <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gpg.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>sign</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <!-- This is necessary for gpg to not try to use the pinentry programs -->
                  <!-- Only required for GPG >= 2.2 -->
                  <!--
                  <gpgArguments>
                    <arg>&#45;&#45;pinentry-mode</arg>
                    <arg>loopback</arg>
                  </gpgArguments>
                  -->
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/redfx-quantum/strange.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:redfx-quantum/strange.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/redfx-quantum/strange</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>

</project>
```

running `mvn package -e` didn't give any noticeably different output and `mvn package -X` didn't give me anything I could understand. How would I go about fixing it? Looking in the pom.xml file, the only release related thing I could see was the `<release>10<\release>` but idk what to change that to if that is the problem. I'm assuming I have to change things in the file to fit what versions of java and maven I have but I'm pretty new to the both of them and don't really know what I'm looking for.

[1]https://github.com/redfx-quantum/strange

Comment: What does an `mvn --version` print out?

Comment: @khmarbaise `Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.6
Java version: 1.8.0_322, vendor: Temurin, runtime: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"`